# Is it possible to keep one text box control above another in .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Friends, Is it possible to keep one text box(or any other asp.net control) above another(let's say total 4 text boxes) in a .aspx page with one text box visible and other 3 invisible(I've done it in windows application)?I've tried with web page but no success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must give it a z-index style with a big value, of course z-index only works if only the position style is defined too.

for example:

```
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;z-index:100;top:0px;left:0px;">
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
```

in this example the second textbox will be on top of the others

Comment: Thank you. It's good idea to keep controls in this manner. My problem is ajaxcontroltoolkit can't extend controls of type inputtext.

Comment: I need example for asp textbox control.

Comment: its exactly the same:  `<asp:Textbox ID="txt" runat="server"  style="position:absolute;z-index:100;top:0px;left:0px;">`

Comment: what a great solution!!It's been a great help of yours..Thanks a lot.